# Irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Is the polynomial $x^{10}+x^9+x^8+x^7+x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_{17}$? I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hint: your polynomial is $(x^{11}-1)/(x-1)$. What can the factors of $x^{11}-1$ be?

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki I don't understand...